# Real Analysis: Monotone And Unbounded Sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Can somebody explain why this statement is true?  **"Since $(a_n)$ is unbounded and monotone, any subsequence is also unbounded"**

Question: True/False: A divergent monotone sequence with a Cauchy subsequence.

Answer: This is not possible. Let $(a_n)$ be a divergent monotone sequence. Then $(a_n)$ is not bounded, since if it were the Monotone Convergence Theorem would imply that $(a_n)$ would converge. **Since $(a_n)$ is unbounded and monotone, any subsequence is also unbounded.** If $(a_n)$ had a Cauchy subsequence, by the Cauchy Criterion, this subsequence would converge and would therefore be bounded, a contradiction. Therefore $(a_n)$ contains no Cauchy subsequences as desired.

Comment: If you had a bounded subsequence, then by monotonicity the entire sequence is bounded by the same bound.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $(a_n)$ is unbounded and monotone, WOLOG let's assume it is increasing. Then for each $n$ we have $a_{n+1} \geq a_n$, and for any $M\in\Bbb{R}$ there is some $N$ so that $a_N > M$.

Let $(a_{n_k})$ be a subsequence. We must show it is unbounded, so let $M \in \Bbb{R}$. We want to find some $K$ so that $a_{n_K} > M$. Since there is some $N$ such that $a_N > M$, and there are only finitely many $n_k$ which are less than $N$, there must be some $K$ with $n_K > N$. But this implies that $a_{n_K} \geq a_N > M$, so $M$ is not a bound for $(a_{n_k})$. But $M$ is arbitrary, so $(a_{n_k})$ is unbounded as required.